# Grub error message on boot

Tags: boot, partitioning, grub2, grub-efi, macbook-pro

I followed [this guide](https://heeris.id.au/2014/ubuntu-plus-mac-pure-efi-boot/#fixing-efi) to get rid of an annoying 40 second white screen delay on my MacBook Pro  (MBP5,2) during boot. As a `TL;DR` it involves deleting Ubuntu's `/boot/efi` partition and then recreating it as a `HFS+` partition and installing grub into that because that's what the Apple firmware wants.

It fixed my original problem, but now after turning on the computer I get a black screen with the following two error messages:

```
error: no server specified.
error: no suitable video mode found.
```

This screen remains for about 10 seconds and then Grub continues to boot the system normally. What do they mean and how can I get rid of them?

I haven't changed anything in my `/etc/default/grub` config and it only contains these lines:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

I did a `sudo upgrade-grub` but the error messages still remain.